# How to Combine two pyqt Forms in one script

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I tried to copy the classes into one script and made it show on new window on click but it does not hide the current window and it closes the new window immediately. When placed in `if __name__ == "__main__":` condition all are opening at the same time. Please help me out.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, although it sounds like you're trying to learn PyQt and Python at the same time. Would you mind editing your question for clarity and showing us the relevant portion of your code?

Comment: i was using qtdesigner , so it is creating seperate py files but when i tried to copy both the classes created into one python and tried to show the other main window  when a button is pressed

Comment: What do you mean by 'copy'? Did you paste the source of the generated classes into your main file? If so, you should probably just import them instead.

Comment: And again, could you please show us the relevant parts of your code?